# Which Proguard version do I need for the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5

Tags: java-me, sun, java-wireless-toolkit

In order to obfuscate my J2MEWTK project I am being instructed to do the following:
[image: J2MEWTK instructions]

However this link is now dead and lacks detail, where can I find a version of Proguard that works with the Sun Wireless Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that version 4.3 works with J2MEWTK, you can find it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/4.3/

Other versions may give you "unsupported major/minor version"